# get text from specific position in listview android

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a ListView with custom_row , every row has a textView1 and a textView2 , the list has now 2 records , and i have a button that is not on the list.
   When i click the button i want to get the text from textView2 of the 2 records.
   Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a shortcut, you `ListView` is being populated by an `Adapter` that uses a dataset. This dataset can be almost any datastructure such as Array, ArrayList, etc.

The layout you define, such as `custom_row` in you case only defines the structure of your view i.e. "where" items will show within on item on the list.

On the other hand, it is still your responsibility to tell the `ListView` "what" to show within the `textView1` and `textView2`. You do this using the `Adapter` which connects the `ListView` to the dataset. More often than not, the `ListView` is a one-to-one mapping of the dataset i.e. the first item on the list is the first item in you dataset (I don't know what you are using for only two items, might be an array).

The `ListView` calls `getCount()` on the `Adapter` to find out how many total views there will be. It then call `getView()` for each view to be shown on the screen. It is in this method that you define what will actually show in a single view on the list (your custom_row).

Now you would know which entry of the dataset is supposed to populate which view in the `ListView` so you can just read it off there. For example, if your `getView()` does:

```
textView2.setText(getItem(position).getSomeTextField());
```

And the original dataset is an ArrayList named `listDataSet`

You could just do `listDataSet.get(2).getSomeTextField()`

**NOTE:** You will have to manage the scope of the dataset so that it's visible from wherever you are calling.

Comment: I don`t understand , sorry if i`m being dumb

Comment: I added some more details. Hope this makes it clear. The important thing to understand is that the `ListView` is just a view. It shows what you tell it to show. Just find out what you are telling it...

Answer (score 1):

Get back your ListView (maybe already stored in an object thanks to findViewById, or by calling [getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29) on your ListActivity).

Then call [getItemAtPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) on your list view, with the position you want.